# Add a local hostname for just my machine

Tags: networking, dns

I have two computers - one that I work on, and one that sits closed so that I can work from home. Since I am frequently using ftp/ssh/scp/etc on this machine, I'd like to be able to do so without typing (and remembering) and IP address.

I don't have access to the DNS server on the network, nor do I want other people knowing that there's something going on on my machine.

Is there a way to add a pre-DNS resolution locally so that I can name my 'server' and connect that way?

I have tried with `avahi-resolve-address`, and it correctly prints the name of my machine (with `.local` appended). However when I use this name, DNS fails (as expected), since I am not really on a home network.

Edits for clarification :
I only want to have this functionality for when I am at work, and only from [computer I bring home] into [computer I leave]. When I'm at home, I will ssh into a third server that is exposed to the internet (with a real DNS entry) and then into my work server. I may add this functionality to that machine as well.

Comment: Give it a static IP address, add the IP to your HOSTS file, and give it a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it absolutely *has* to be locally, the only way is to determine the address dynamically assigned to the machine you want to connect to (you will have to ask the router or to utilize one of these "determine my IP" web pages), and add a `/etc/hosts` entry to your mobile computer before departing. This will stop working whenever the internet provider assigns a new IP address to your "server" computer (might be once every 24h, or after disconnecting/reconnecting).

Using a dynamic DNS service might be preferable; but then other persons (e.g. the dynamic DNS provider) would know, too. But on the other hand, just hiding the IP address may *not* be considered as a security feature.

Comment: Why do I have to know the IP of my home machine? I'm going into the work machine, not into the home machine.

Comment: @BrydonGibson: ah, swapped it to my own use-case. Of course you need the IP addr of the machine you want to connect to. Edited.

Comment: Did not realise it was as easy as editing the hosts file, thank you!